# How to configur SMTP mailing on my hosting server in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I m trying to send an automated email from my hosting server using codeigniter smtp, but here i m facing some error with AUTH LOGIN. Successfully i can able to sending mails in my localhost with gmail smtp host,  and gmail account (after allowing security for third-party apps). Here i m using webmail, so i help form you guys to fix my bugs. Thanks in Advance.

**ERROR :-**
The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: DATA

data: 
The following SMTP error was encountered:     **etc....**

**Here is my code:-**

```
    $config['useragent']='CodeIgniter';
    $config['protocol']='smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']='ssl//mail.mydomain.com';
    $config['smtp_port']='587';
    $config['smtp_auth']=true;
    $config['smtp_timeout']='30';
    $config['smtp_user']= 'admin@mydomain.com';
    $config['smtp_pass']= 'mypassword';
    $config['charset']='utf-8';
    $config['newline']="\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($from, $from_name);
    $this->email->reply_to($from, $from_name);
```

Comment: The error means, that the smtp server does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use email library of codeigniter because it will be easy to your in email library we have to no needed to set up a SMTP mail we can send mail directly and also email library will be helpful to you in case of attachment because codeigniter by default provide `attachment()`  method only we have to pass path in attachment method so it will be easy to you...

you can use like that --

```
public function supportEmail()
    {
      $this->load->library('email');
      $this->email->from('saurav@gmail.com', 'Saurav Garg');
      $this->email->to('info@demo.com');
      $this->email->subject('Live Support');
      $this->email->message('Please Use This Method');
      $sent = $this->email->send();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply... from my side everything is okay, but in server there they didn't configured it properly, So email are not sending with mydomain, i tested with php basic email function.

Comment: don't know.. in basic email nothing is showing, and in codeigniter shows as      "The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:"